# Previously working call to send SMS msg via TWILIO is now failing with... "Unsupported SSL context options are set."

Tags: php, google-app-engine, ssl, twilio

This has been working fine for awhile and I haven't changed a thing. The code runs on Google AppEngine, which may have changed something in the past 12 hours that would cause this??

**Here's the full error message**:

> HP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5788e1bf9a85f308ed805dc57b1111/Messages.json):
>   failed to open stream: Unsupported SSL context options are set. The
>   following options are present, but have been ignored: cafile,
>   verify_depth Request deadline exceeded in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~vivonoteapp/1.371473117917944991/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php
>   on line 62

By the way, here is line 62 referenced above (no change since when it was working):

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
```

And here's my code that results in line 62 being called (no change since when it was working):

```
$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(get_twilio_number(), // FROM
                                               $sender, // TO
                                               $msg);
```

Thanks for any thoughts.
Liz

Answer (score 1):

The actual error is 'Request deadline exceeded', the other messages are warning which are letting you know that some of the SSL options you're supplying are not used by the URLFetch implementation.

You can try extending the deadline of the request by passing a larger [timeout value](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) in the http options that you pass to stream_context_create.

```
$options = [ 
  'http' => [
    'timeout' => 60.0,
  ],
];
```

Also, there was a URLFetch outage yesterday that might explain your problems as well. Details [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/aRJ9F1FJv2o).